# How to provide cellformatter in gwt Celltable

Tags: gwt

How can I set the cell format on a table cell? Any ideas how to make this happen

From my database I am getting "1000" but I need to display like currency "$1000"

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a NumberFormat when you return a String:

```
private static NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyFormat("USD");
...
TextColumn<MyObject> amountColumn = new TextColumn<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public String getValue(MyObject myObject) {
        return currencyFormat.format(myObject.getAmount());
    }
};
```

Comment: can we do this on render,when to use getvalue and render

Comment: You only use `render` if you need to override the standard behavior. For all standard columns, `getValue` is all you need.

Comment: Thanks volgin(+1)..Yes i got this currency format..but for the same i need to add handler .how to add ?

Comment: This sounds like a different question. Search the StackOverflow or post a new question.